# Django filter products in admin and add create anew product of the combination

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-filter

I am creating an outfit app where I have three models Product , Category , Outfit . My product Model has fields (Title, Slug, Price,image-url,color,pattern, ) Category has fields (title ,description, and product as foreign key to product) outfit has (title, description, and products with many to many to product)

My question is after I add these models to admin I want create outfits from admin panel and here is where I am stuck . How do I add multiple products to the outfit from admin panel,  I have a large database so selecting from drop down menu is not option what I would like to have is filterset on product with all fields and when I filter displays the products want to select all the filtered products and add them to the outfit .

TO BE MORE CLEAR HERE IS AN EXAMPLE 
There is one outfit with burgundy stripe shirt , navy blue cargo ,black leather belt ,and brown suede loafers . Now in my admin when creating an outfit I need to add all these products from my product Model by filtering shirt with (color :burgundy and pattern: stripe ) then cargo with (navy blue : color ) belt with (leather : material ) and loafers with (material : suede and color : brown)  As you can see different products need to be filtered differently  please suggest me how can I achieve this open to change my model structure I want implement this in best possible way

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried filter_horizontal?
[Admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal)

Comment: No can you give an example on how to do it I have only tried with filterset , does filter_horizontal can filter multiple attributes ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to customize the admin somehow like this

```
#models.py
class Outfit(models.Model):

    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

#admin.py
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple

class OutfitForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    products = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        required=False,
        queryset=Product.objects.all(),
        widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("Products", is_stacked=False),
        label='')


class OutfitFormAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = OutfitForm
    list_display = ('title', 'description', 'products')
    fieldsets = (
        ('General', {
            'fields': (
                'title',
                'description'
            )
        }),
        ('Select products', {
            'fields': ('products',)
        }),
    )
```

Comment: Pavan your solution definitely addresses how I can select multiple fields and add it my outfit , but the problem I am facing is in my product Model has different attributes relating to one product for eg  A shirt product has attributes color, pattern , etc i want to select these attributes and filter the results then add that item to my outfit , in your example I am getting a search bar to filter multiple products but there is no way to select these attributes